# click through rate calculation in Hadoop Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Need to calculate CTR (count of clicks over count of impressions, at country level), I list table structure (impression table and click table), and my code in Hadoop Pig. My question is whether below implementation is most efficient, any more efficient solutions? Thanks.

table impression:

impressionID, timestamp, countryID

click table:

impressionID, timestamp

```
joined_feed = join impression by impressionID, click by impression ID;
joined_feed = foreach joined_feed generate impression::countryID, click::impressionID is null? 0 : 1 as clicked;
ctr_result = foreach (group joined_feed by country) generate group as countryID, SUM(clicked)/COUNT(joined_feed)
```

Comment: For such code you should get CTR equal to 1. As far as I understand you should have left join here. Moreover it would be great to have country in clicks table. Then you can aggregate clicks and impressions separately and join by countryID, which be much faster.

Comment: In every map/reduce stage of the join, the last table in the sequence is  streamed through the reducers where as the others are buffered.  Therefore, it helps to reduce the memory needed in the reducer for  buffering the rows for a particular value of the join key by organizing  the tables such that the largest tables appear last in the sequence

Comment: @zuku, good catch. For left join, I think it is to make sure impressions without click could also have a record in final output to calculate CTR, correct?

Comment: @Havnar, thanks for your advice, for your comments, "the largest tables appear last in the sequence", which specific line of code do you mean?

Comment: In a join, put the biggest table last

Comment: @Havnar, vote up. :)

Could you elaborate a bit more why? How "memory needed in the reducer for buffering the rows" related to the order of table alias? An example, is appreciated. :)

Comment: this is just how hive works, you could dig trough the source code and look into the documentation for further clarification. it just joins this way since the abstraction is written like that. Since hive doesn't know your data, you should make sure you do so you can write better hive queries.

Comment: @Havnar, I am using Pig, not Hive, are they the same behavior underlying internally? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way to get ctr is pretty effective though you should add type cast or you will get bunch of zeros and ones

```
ctr_result = foreach (group joined_feed by country) generate group as countryID, (double) SUM(clicked)/(double) COUNT(joined_feed) as ctr
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey, vote up. Wondering if order of table matters as @Havnar mentioned above? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa See https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/perf.html#replicated-joins
if you want to improve performance (and if  you click table is small enough)

Comment: Thanks Alexey, vote up. I know replicated join. My question is more about for normal join in Pig, does order of tables matter performance? You can refer the discussion between Havnar and me above. :)

Comment: @LinMa Yep, he's right, larger table should be on the right to reduce memory usage if you are using hash join (default). Finally found it in O'Reilly
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch05.html#join_basic see the last  paragraph

Comment: Thanks Alexey, want to confirm with you this is the right part which related to why left side table should be smaller? -- "Thus all of the records for the left input arrive first. Pig caches these in memory. All of the records for the right input arrive second. As each of these records arrives, it is crossed with each record from the left side to produce an output record. In a multiway join, the left n - 1 inputs are held in memory, and the nth is streamed through." (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) "It is important to keep this in mind when writing joins in your Pig queries if you know that one of your inputs has more records per value of the chosen key. Placing that input on the right side of your join will lower memory usage and possibly increase your script’s performance."?

Comment: Thanks Alexey, mark your reply as answer. Have a good day. :)